# Vaadin ckEditor addon has two panels

Tags: ckeditor, vaadin, vaadin7

[image]

No matter what I do when I run the latest version of ckEditor I have two panels on my screen. Both are populated with data. Although you can only see one editor in full on the screenshot if I increase the height you can see both editors. I've brought the code down to the bare minimum. It use to work but in the latest version I always have two editors no matter what I do, and no matter what browser I use.

Also when I call `getValue()` on the editor it always brings back the value of the bottom editor. I've confirmed this by putting different values in the different editors.

My code is:

```
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
{
    CKEditorTextField ckEditorTextField = new CKEditorTextField();

    ckEditorTextField.setValue("hello world");
    ckEditorTextField.setHeight("500px");
    ckEditorTextField.setWidth("500px");

    setContent(ckEditorTextField);
}
```

And yes I know I should use `CKEditorConfig` but I've tried to minimize all code to the bare minimum. I've also tried with layouts and it makes no difference. The reason I put the height and width is to make it more visible, but it's not required. Also this code is called on the main `UI` class.

Comment: The answer can be found at the bottom of this thread: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/2963857/2963856 I'll post the answer in 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that an upgrade to Vaadin hadn't properly taken, there were still some caching issues. The way to resolve it can be found here: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/2963857/2963856

The steps are:

1. Ivy-> Clean all caches
2. Ivy -> Resolve
3. Reboot Eclipse
4. Compile Vaadin widgets